# How to add a sepfootnote's footnote inside entry name field with glossaries-extra and bib2gls?

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls, sepfootnotes

I  use `glossaries-extra` via `bib2gls -g` to generate a glossary. Consider the following glossary entry placed in file `entriesTest.bib`:

```
@entry{test-entry,
name={fake name\sepfootnote{A}},
text={},
description={fictional description}
}
```

The entry `test-entry` name field `fake name\sepfootnote{A}` has a footnote, made with package `sepfootnotes` command pair `\sepfootnotecontent{<label>}{<content>}` and `\sepfootnote{<label>}`.

This does not work as planned. The footnote inside `name={}` does not work. As the following pictures exemplifies,

- the footnote mark has an incorrect value (too high);
- no footnote text appears in the page footer (and therefore, link also leads to incorrect location).

The warning message `name{Hfootnote.7} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one` is also displayed.

***Q:*** How to fix this issue?

If the footnote is instead added under `description={}`, everything seems to work.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[global]{sepfootnotes} 
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[record, stylemods={default}, style={alttreehypergroup}]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entriesTest}, break-at={none}]

\begin{document}
    Sample text. \sepfootnotecontent{A}{Illustrative footnote content}
    \gls*{test-entry}
    \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]}
    {\printunsrtglossary[type=main]}
\end{document}
```

And the pictures of output to confirm (red text added by hand; red boxes are the links added by `hyperref`):

[image: Problem with footnote name field]
[image: No footnote text]

Comment: Footnotes do not generally work in `tabular` environments. If you put a *tabular* into the `description` field and add a footnote, it doesn't work there either.

Comment: I think you'd do better to get the footnotes working without the tabular, if you can, and then ask how to format the name to your liking. You need to check your glossary style isn't using an environment antithetical to footnotes, too. (I don't know what `tree` styles use.) This is all if you want hyperlinking. If you give up hyperlinking, you could make the marks and then spit out the text later. `hyperref` has limited support for footnotes (according to its manual).

Comment: @cfr I have edited OP to remove `tabular` altogether. Hopefully, this does not break someone's yet-to-be-posted solution.

Comment: It half works to add the footnote text at the beginning of the `description` and only the mark in `name`. Is there an equivalent of the entry/longentry distinction with `bib2gls`? If so, have you tried both?

Comment: I suspect `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` is responsible for at least some of the number inflation. It would probably be possible to fix that and get the footnotes working (perhaps separating the mark from the text in the same way you do for `tabular`s and `minipage`s etc.), but I can't see that working with hyperlinks. `hyperref` doesn't support the optional argument when making marks/text. So even if you got something to kind-of work, I suspect it would be fragile. (But I don't know how `sepfootnotes` works - it seems OK with `hyperref` even with separation of marks/texts in the standard case.)

Comment: @cfr 1) Replacing the style to `long3col` from `alttreehypergroup` seems to add the missing footnote text into page footer, and lowers the counter from `4` to `3`. Removing `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname` lowers the counter from `3` to `2`. However, either of these introduce other layout problems which might be be at least as difficult to solve. In my main document, further customisation has been done which does not seem possible with `long3col` out of the box. I am not sure if this is what you meant by `entry/longentry`. 2) Yes, `sepfootnotes` usually work great.