# Broken footnotebackref's links to footnotes inside glossary made with longtable

Tags: footnotes, longtable, glossaries-extra, bib2gls, sepfootnotes

I have created a glossary style (based on existing style). It does not possess the more severe issues with footnotes that my previous approaches did. Nevertheless, one footnote-related problem persists.

- Links made with [`footnotebackref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/footnotebackref?lang=en) link to the beginning of the document. The expected behaviour is to link back to the glossary entry with the footnote.

***Q**: How to fix these links?*

Other links such as the link from the footnotemark to the bottom of the page function correctly.

The new glossary style is based on `longtable`, which handles footnotes better than `tabular` or `alttreehypergroup` style, for instance. Footnote texts and marks themselves are separated by [`sepfootnotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes), with footnotetext appearing in preamble and footnotemarks in a `.bib`-file to be compiled with `bib2gls`.

---

See minimally working example. The style itself has also been simplified.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}                                    % for cftdotfill
\usepackage{array}                                      % m-type column in longtable
\usepackage{longtable}                                  % longtable for glossary
%\usepackage[symbol*, multiple]{footmisc}               % (In real document, used primarily for changing footnote style)
\usepackage[global]{sepfootnotes}                       % for separation of footnotemark and text but toward still using hyperlinks
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}                % testing for boundaries
\newgeometry{margin=2.5cm}

%% Footnotetexts %%
\sepfootnotecontent{A}{long fake name's footnote}
\sepfootnotecontent{B}{short fake name's footnote}
\sepfootnotecontent{C}{subentry fake name's footnote}
\sepfootnotecontent{D}{different fake name's footnote}

%%%%% FOR GLOSSSARY (Begins below) %%%%%
\usepackage[record, stylemods={default}]{glossaries-extra}                  % main glossary package
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entriesTest}, break-at={none}]                    % loading glossary file entriesTest.bib (for bib2gls)
\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}                                          % glossary longtable styles, commands etc

% Some basic formatting of glossary %
\def\myglsdefaultnamefmt#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\myglsnavigationfmt#1{\myglsdefaultnamefmt{#1}}
\def\myglsnavigationfmtSpecial#1{{\hspace{5em}\Large\myglsdefaultnamefmt{#1}}}
\newcommand\mySpaceInGlsSub{2em}
%%

% Dots in glossary %
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
%%

%% Actual glossary style definition is here %%
\makeatletter
\ifcsdef{@glsstyle@longragged3col}
{%
    \renewglossarystyle{longragged3col}{%
        \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
            \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
            \setlength\LTright{0pt}
            \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}m{5cm}>{\raggedright}m{\dimexpr\textwidth-5cm-2\tabcolsep}@{}}}%
            {\end{longtable}}%
        \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
            \par
            \def\@gls@prevlevel{-1}%
            \hangindent0pt\relax
            \parindent0pt\relax
            \myglsnavigationfmt{\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{0.98\textwidth}\glsnavigation}}
            \glsgroupskip
            \glsgroupskip
        }%
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
            \glsxtrgetgrouptitle{##1}{\glsxtr@grptitle}%
            \glstreePreHeader{##1}{\glsxtr@grptitle}%
            \myglsnavigationfmtSpecial{\glsnavhypertarget{##1}{\glsxtr@grptitle\,\MakeLowercase{\glsxtr@grptitle}}}%
            \def\@gls@prevlevel{-1}%
            \hangindent0pt\relax
            \parindent0pt\relax
            \glsgroupskip
        }%
        \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
            \glsentryitem{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1} \glspostdescription\ ##2\tabularnewline
        }%
        \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
            \hspace{\mySpaceInGlsSub}\hangindent\mySpaceInGlsSub\glssubentryitem{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}} &
            \hspace{\mySpaceInGlsSub}\hangindent\mySpaceInGlsSub{\glossentrydesc{##2}}\glspostdescription\ ##3\tabularnewline
        }%
        \ifglsnogroupskip
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
        \else
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{&\tabularnewline}%
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
%%%%
%%%%% FOR GLOSSSARY (Ends above) %%%%%

\begin{document}
    Lala.\footnote{test} \newpage
    \gls*{test-entry}
    \gls*{test-entryII}
    \gls*{test-entryIII}
    \gls*{test-entryIV}
    \gls*{test-entryV}
    \gls*{test-entryVI}
    \newcommand{\TitleOfGlossary}{Title of Glossary}
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    {\footnotesize\printunsrtglossary[type=main,style={longragged3col},title={\protect\Large\centering\TitleOfGlossary\pagestyle{empty}},toctitle=\TitleOfGlossary]}
\end{document}
```

Auxiliary `entriesTest.bib`

```
@entry{test-entry,
name={fake name\sepfootnote{A}, but with a longish text to make sure there is some text wrapping},
text={},
description={fictional description}
}

@entry{test-entryII,
name={fake name\sepfootnote{B}},
text={},
description={fictional description B}
}

@entry{test-entryIII,
parent={test-entryII},
name={fake subname that also spans multiple lines\sepfootnote{C}},
text={},
description={fictional description C}
}

@entry{test-entryIV,
name={different fake name},
text={},
description={fictional description D\sepfootnote{D}}
}

@entry{test-entryV,
name={f' yet another fake name with longer text indeed},
text={},
description={Am I indented properly?}
}

@entry{test-entryVI,
parent={test-entryV},
name={f' yet another fake subname with long text yes},
text={},
description={But am I indented properly? Especially when I am also line broken? What about my vertical spacing?}
}
```

Output with clarifying annotation

[image: Output of MWE with a clarifying annotation]

Comment: One previous approach is outlined in [*How to add a sepfootnote's footnote inside entry name field with glossaries-extra and bib2gls?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/696074/116907). NO need to read it. I have seen [*Hyperref + footnotebackref in longtable*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137594/116907) and tried the [given solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139496/116907), but it did not work out.

Comment: sorry but I refuse to think about backref links (for footnotes but also for other things). It simply does make much sense. You can have more than one mark pointing to a footnote and so there is no way to know how to go back (the tagging code produces an array (!) of References but only because the spec requires it not because I can see currently a sensible use). Use Alt + left arrow instead to go back where you came from.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see. One can probably live without the backreferences to footnotes if necessary. However, I thought giving it a try even if only as a "canary" to probe whether things are working well. After all, a package for footnote backreferences seems to exist which functions in normal text. I agree that one must choose between using one-mark-per-footnote and backreferences, or the non-injective alternative without backreferences. I have no idea how to get these multiple-marks-per-footnote working in this case, so the choice for me was clear. :-)